# This program spending too much time,even no respond,is there any way to improve it?

Tags: delphi, popup

1, Add a popupmenu named `PopupMenu1`

2, Add a menuitem named `TestMI`

3, Add a Button

and code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MItems: array of TMenuItem;
  SList: TStringList;
  FileRec: TSearchrec;
  i: integer;
begin

  SList := TStringList.Create;
 //3000+ files 
  if FindFirst('C:\Windows\System32\*', faNormal or faDirectory, FileRec) = 0
    then
    repeat
      if (FileRec.Name = '.') or (FileRec.Name = '..') then
        Continue;

      SList.Add(FileRec.Name);

    until FindNext(FileRec) <> 0;
  FindClose(FileRec);

  if SList.Count > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(MItems, SList.Count);
    for i := 0 to SList.Count - 1 do
    begin

      MItems[i] := TMenuItem.Create(TestMI);
      MItems[i].Caption := SList[i];

    end;

    TestMI.Add(MItems);

  end;
end;
```

When I click button , it's OK , but when i popup  `PopupMenu1` and move on  `TestMI`，Because too many files it no respond.

Is there any way to solve it?

Updata :

I have to use PopupMenu to do this .

I find a program , can do it fast , take 150ms

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1sDNMAzGE2oZWpTWlpWNHJGZzQ

it use [**BarMenu Components**](http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Menus/BarMenu_Components-info.html)

but i can't compile in Delphi 2009.
Error :

lib\BarMenus:

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  {$IFNDEF DFS_COMPILER_5_UP}
     {$MESSAGE FATAL 'You need Delphi 5 or higher in order to compile this unit.'}
  {$ENDIF}
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Menus, Forms;
{$ENDIF}
```

update to @Sertac Akyuz

you solution is useful , in first case. and very thank you.
and i change that case 
Code :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Variants,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  StdCtrls,
  Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    TestMI: TMenuItem;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CreMI(MI: TMenuItem);
    procedure IMonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddSubEmpItem(MI: TMenuItem);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.IMonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  CreMI(TMenuItem(Sender));

end;

procedure TForm1.AddSubEmpItem(MI: TMenuItem);
var
  EmpIM: TMenuItem;
begin

  EmpIM := TMenuItem.Create(MI);
  with EmpIM do
  begin
    Caption := '(Folder empty)';
    Enabled := False;
    Hint := '';
    MI.Add(EmpIM);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.CreMI(MI: TMenuItem);
var
  MItems: array of TMenuItem;
  SList: TStringList;
  FileRec: TSearchrec;
  i: integer;
begin

  if (MI.Items[0].Caption = '(Folder empty)') and (MI.Count = 1) then
  begin

    SList := TStringList.Create;

    if FindFirst(MI.Hint + '\*', faNormal or faDirectory, FileRec) = 0
      then
      repeat
        if (FileRec.Name = '.') or (FileRec.Name = '..') then
          Continue;

        SList.Add(FileRec.Name);

      until FindNext(FileRec) <> 0;

    FindClose(FileRec);

    if SList.Count > 0 then
    begin

      SetLength(MItems, SList.Count);
      for i := 0 to SList.Count - 1 do
      begin

        MItems[i] := TMenuItem.Create(MI);
        MItems[i].Caption := SList[i];
        MItems[i].Hint := MI.Hint + SList[i] + PathDelim;
        AddSubEmpItem(MItems[i]);
        MItems[i].OnClick := IMonClick;
        MItems[i].AutoHotkeys := maManual;

      end;

      MI.Add(MItems);
      MI.AutoHotkeys := maManual;

    end;
  end;
  //Button1.Caption := IntToStr(MI.Count);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

  AddSubEmpItem(TestMI);
  CreMI(TestMI);


end;

end.
```

Set `TestMI.Hint := C:\`

Click the button and when I move on `C:\ -> Windows -> System32`  it no respond too.
can you give some adviese?

Comment: You can move your long running stuff (file list fetch) to a worker thread. During that time you can't populate the result since it won't be completed, but your application start to respond. But anyway, are you sure, you want to build a popup menu from 3000+ items ?

Comment: It's going to be hard to beat `FindFirst`/`FindNext`. The problem is not the implementation. Rather the problem is the design.

Comment: this is... just painful, my clean system install of w7 has a little over 2.8k of files, it's going to take some time to add them, also, I see no real value in adding so many menu items, the UI concept is flawed IMHO.

Comment: @ONIon - Have you tested to set AutoHotKeys to maManual as in my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test shows the time is spent in `InternalRethinkHotkeys`. Hot keys won't help with a menu with > 3000 items. Just disable it:

```
    ..
    TestMI.Add(MItems);
    TestMI.AutoHotkeys := maManual; // <--

  end;
end;
```

Having said that, also consider using some other gui element like a list box etc., scrolling through that much items in a menu is practically impossible.

Comment: You're welcome. Summing up my comment to the question: what's different with your second version is that, items have got handles now since you're populating them after they have been popped up. This requires rebuilding of items with every added item by VCL design. You can *probably* bypass that design by populating a brand new popup instead and then attaching that popup to the corresponding menu item. Maybe something like the 'AttachPopup' [here](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200912/0912146360.html) from an old newsgroups post of mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume that you're really smart enough to know that creating a menu with a million items in  it is silly, so let's take this as an opportunity to just discuss technical matters, because as all the commenters say, your idea is not workable, but perhaps in your real program you're going to build a list of word documents in a folder only on your computer, so you picked the Windows folder for sake of illustration only. So let us proceed then:

A  beginning Delphi programmer would probably insert `Application.ProcessMessages` call in there, and now, your application will not show "not responding", however you would be introducing some potential for bad things (including crashes) happening, depending on what goes on in the rest of your application.   If this is a throwaway program, I would be tempted to simply add the "Application.ProcessMessages" call (once ever 100 times through the loop or so), and my app would not show "not responding".

However in a real-stable-production code environment you should be separating your UI building code (view builder) from your background worker thread.

And a worker thread is not going to be trivial to implement either, because you are effectively working on building a menu using VCL classes that are not supposed to be accessed from the background threads.  If you really want to generate a popup menu with 100,000 items in it, there's no nice fast way to do it.

I suggest you should think about some object oriented design:

1. worker thread with a limit on how large a list of items it will build.
2. When worker thread completes the `FindFirst` loop, and moves on to creating menu items, consider using `TThread.Synchronize()` or some other safe means to make sure that the  the method that will add a menu item, which is invoked from a background thread, can do so safely.

**Update** Edits to this question have rendered this answer rather out of date. Sadly the question is a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> When I click button , it's OK

So I assume that the file search is quick, and it's adding the menu options quickly, so a background thread isn't going to solve your problem.  Your problem is that you are stuffing thousands of entries into a menu, which is not going to work.  You need to re-think.  Maybe a listbox would be better. Be sure to use BeginUpdate/EndUpdate to enclose your loop.

Comment: Sorry , i have to use PopupMenu